# How to reinitialize Google map API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to the coding part.So I am in need for your kind ideas.

How can i reinitialize the loaded Google map API in one HTML page (eg: MapView.html) from parent HTML page using `IFRAME` tag?

Is there any possibilities to reload the Google map to view the updated markers in new page without pressing F5 key?

Comment: you can use javascript...

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but can you explain with some examples...

Comment: can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe part makes it very difficult as iframe is used basically for accepting content from an external source without any changes. It would be easier if you injected the script which utilizes Google Map in every page you use it.

I don't understand much what you mean by parent HTML :( If it is a single-page  application and the child HTML is a subview of the parent, you could be able to access the parent HTML's controller but I have the feeling that this is not the case :)

So generally you can reinitialize the map using JavaScript. Have a look in the API Reference for all the options:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

If you could create the map in your child HTML, the Marker can be created and updated by following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), yourMapOptions); // This is the map initiation in a #map element
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(...), // the old position
    map: map, // The map you created in your element by new google.maps.Map(...)
    icon: 'assets/marker.png',
    title: 'This is the pointer',
});

setTimeout(function() {
    marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(...); // new position
    marker.setMap(map); // This reinitializes the marker
}, 10000); // For this example I set a 10s timeout
```

Sorry if the iframe is an important thing but without any code I assumed this could help you more than hacking an iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your effort... i need to reinitialize without using setTimeout() i.e by manually....

Comment: You don't need the timeout :) That was just as a showcase. You can have a function defined and call it onclick or window resize or whatever you desire. The main issue is that if you use an iframe, there is not much to do with the map because you ar only served the content. If you create the map using your own script, you are able to do whatever the Google API lets you. The example is shown inside the callback function inside the setTimeout. The most important part for you is "marker.setMap()".

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I had fixed it by calling the initialization() method again instead of loading the entire HTML page into the <div>. It loads only the content of google map and its marker perfectly....